# Random Forest plot standardized

Tags: python, random-forest, machine-learning-model, decision-trees

For a data science project, I first used a standardized scaler on data in python, ran random forest then plotted the tree. However, the values of the decisions are in their standardized form. How do I plot the unscaled data?

Example: as is: decision node based on Age <= 2.04 desired: decision node based on Age <= 30

Answer (score 0):

Decision tree based models (incl. Random Forest) are scale invariant. You can just feed the unscaled data in and plot.

Reference [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255765/does-random-forest-need-input-variables-to-be-scaled-or-centered).

Comment: Due to the nature of the dataset, the unstandardised features do not offer at least a satisfactory accuracy

Comment: @firedonut123 as said, *Random Forest is scale invariant* i.e. there is no performance difference with unstandardised vs. standardised features for it. Otherwise, please kindly provide a minimal reproducible code sample so we can verify.